# Regex only first ocurrence of string

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a heard time getting this to work:

https://regex101.com/r/F9MpoN/1

I need only the "14" so the first ocurrence of something, which comes before "days".

I know I can remove the "/g" flag, however I am forced using a tool, which doesn't let me do this (long story). That's also why I don't have any code, I just input the regex and that's it.

So I don't know how I can adjust this, to maybe use a quantifier or something similar.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript? May you share that code as well?

Comment: Your regex101 link indicates you are using PHP. If that then ```preg_match``` returns the first match.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sorry no Javascript/PHP and also no Code. It's a specific tool I use, where I can enter a Regex to extract a value. Currently it extracts both values and I only want one.

Comment: @user5417542 What are the rules for regexes in the tool you're using? Does `^[^0-9]*(\d+)(?=\sdays)` give any useful result?

Answer (score 0):

How about [this way](https://regex101.com/r/F9MpoN/3), the equivalent of:

```
Search:  ^.*?(\d+) days
Replace: $1
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked @Jonas Byström's answer...so if it's not always a number before "days' (e.g., sixty days) but does have word boundaries try...

```
^.*? (.*?) days
```